# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.5

I have got this kind of code:

*models.py*:

```
from django.db import models
import ioweyou.settings as settings
from comment.models import Comment


class Entry(models.Model):

    OPEN = 0
    ACCEPTED = 1
    REJECTED = 2
    DELETED = 3
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (OPEN, 'Open'),
        (ACCEPTED, 'Accepted'),
        (REJECTED, 'Rejected'),
        (DELETED, 'Deleted'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField('entry description', blank=True, null=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    lender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, related_name='lender')
    debtor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, related_name='debtor')
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    accepted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    rejected_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class EntryComment(Comment):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, null=False, related_name="comments")
```

*admin.py*

```
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['name']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['accepted_at']}),
    ]

admin.site.register(models.Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

and this kind of error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/entry/entry/116/
'unicode' object has no attribute 'date'

Error during template rendering
In template /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
```

django and python have been dealing with recently. And my knowledge is not complete. Is anyone able to help me?

Error occurs when you try to edit the Entry and the value of the field accepted_at is determined (set already).

Comment: Please show us the full models.py.  You may believe that this is the piece of code that contains the error, but most of the time, people thinking so are terribly wrong.

Comment: The error page should also contain the traceback.

Comment: I hope I give all the necessary information.